# Loop to save data in directory and print on python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, caching, httprequest

I am writing a code that converts currency. I write down my code below there is a wrong loop in the last of the program. At first, I try to make comment on code when it's get nested I leave it there, sorry for that. May you find everything you need to help me.

**The basic function of the program is:**

1. take `first_currency` as a base currency code. `first_currency` to `second_currency` will converted. and the third input is `user_money`. code will be in the loop, `second_currency` and `user_money` are changeable every time, not the base `first_currency`.
2. program will save `first_currency` to USD and EUR rate automatically as cache, and others will be saved after the first covert and stay in the cache for that RUN.
3. 2nd line of `print` will different base on the **"RATE"** if it's on Cache to need to extract from JSON file.

**The thing I need help with**

1. look at ** the last block of code**, I need to assign the right condition for the loop. wanted to use `for` but can't find the condition. instead, I use `while` for now. But not getting an expected output.

please look below **my output** and **expected output**

2. please advise me, if there is anything that could improve the code. I am new :)

** ****I know my code looks like shit. But, please consider. I am new. And leave your advice to improve this shit.** ** **

Thanks in advance.
Sumtu

```
# import section
import requests

# import first currency
first_currency = str.lower(input())

# url for FloatRates website.
url_ = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/' + first_currency + '.json'

# json file request
request = requests.get(url_).json()

sample_cache = ['usd', 'eur']
# while loop
while True:
    second_currency = str.lower(input())
    user_money = float(input())

    if second_currency == "":
        break

    else:
        if second_currency in sample_cache and \
                first_currency not in sample_cache:
            first_currency_to_usd = request['usd']['rate']
            first_currency_to_euro = request['eur']['rate']
            cache_2 = {
                'usd': first_currency_to_usd,
                'eur': first_currency_to_euro
            }
            rate = cache_2[second_currency]
            exchange = round((rate * user_money), 2)
            print("Checking the cache...")
            print("Oh! It is in the cache!")
            print("You received", exchange, second_currency.upper() + ".")
            print('i am 36')

        elif first_currency in sample_cache and \
                second_currency in sample_cache:
            cache_3 = {}

            if first_currency != 'eur':
                first_currency_to_euro = request['eur']['rate']
                cache_3['eur'] = first_currency_to_euro
                rate = cache_3[second_currency]
                exchange = round((rate * user_money), 2)
                print("Checking the cache...")
                print("Oh! It is in the cache!")
                print("You received", exchange, second_currency.upper() + ".")

            elif first_currency != 'usd':
                first_currency_to_usd = request['usd']['rate']
                cache_3['usd'] = first_currency_to_usd
                rate = cache_3[second_currency]
                exchange = round((rate * user_money), 2)
                print("Checking the cache...")
                print("Oh! It is in the cache!")
                print("You received", exchange, second_currency.upper() + ".")
        else:
            cache_four = {}
            if second_currency in cache_four.keys():
                rate = cache_four[second_currency]
                exchange = round((rate * user_money), 2)
                print("Checking the cache...")
                print("Oh! It is in the cache!")
                print("You received", exchange, second_currency.upper() + ".")

            while second_currency not in cache_four:
                if second_currency not in sample_cache:
                rate = request[second_currency]['rate']
                cache_four[second_currency] = rate
                exchange = round((user_money * rate), 2)
                print("Checking the cache...")
                print("Sorry, but it is not in the cache!")
                print("You received", exchange, second_currency.upper() + ".")
```

**Output**

```
# > USD
# > EUR
# > 20

# Checking the cache...
# Oh! It is in the cache!
# You received 16.58 EUR.

# > NOK
# > 55

# Checking the cache...
# Sorry, but it is not in the cache!
# You received 457.68 NOK.

# > NOK
# > 66

# Checking the cache...
# Sorry, but it is not in the cache!
# You received 549.22 NOK.
```

**Expected Output**

```
# > USD
# > EUR
# > 20

# Checking the cache...
# Oh! It is in the cache!
# You received 16.58 EUR.

# > NOK
# > 55

# Checking the cache...
# Sorry, but it is not in the cache!
# You received 457.68 NOK.

# > NOK
# > 66

# Checking the cache...
# Oh! It is in the cache!
# You received 549.22 NOK.
```